# UK visitor visa refund if the visa already issued

Tags: visas, uk, covid-19

In the beginning of 2020, I applied for and was granted a UK visitor visa for 6 months. Its starting date was April 1st and it will expire in September. Theoretically, I will be able to enter as I am a resident of the EU (not a citizen), but it is unlikely I will travel this summer.

Do you know if it is possible to cancel visa due to COVID-19 and get a refund (at least partial) for the fees I paid?

Comment: I can only find that you can cancel an application for a refund due to Covid 19, but not for any issued visa so far. The fee is nominally for the processing of the visa application, not the visa itself. I don't think it's likely to get a refund, but you might get fees waived or reduced for a new visa if UK decides so later.

Answer (score 14):

Your application is processed, the work is done, the visa issued.

The UK border has remained open during the pandemic so far. Further, it is likely that travel restrictions in Europe will be eased enough for you to visit the UK before your visa expires in September.

It is essentially your choice, then, not to use your visa. It is extremely unlikely that you could get a refund.

However, you could try sending an email to CIH@homeoffice.gov.uk. Full details of how to apply are given [here](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa)

Comment: The uk.gov website cited in the answer speaks of refunds for "applications," and makes no mention of refunds for already-issued visas. For exactly the reasons stated by Arthur's Pass in the answer, I expect you will not be successful in getting a refund for an already-issued visa.